# Justifying cells in table

Tags: tables

In the following table, I want to place the `Name` in the center of the cell while the next row `aaaaa-bbbbbb` and `ddddd` in the left of the cell. How can I fix the following figure?

```
 \begin{table}
    \centering
    \caption{X}
    \label{d}
    \begin{tabular}{|l|c|c|}
        \hline
        name    & X    & Y \\
        \hline
        aaaaa-bbbbbb & * & ** \\
        ddddd & ** & * \\
        \hline
    \end{tabular}
\end{table}
```

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Like this:

[image]

With `tabularray` package is simple:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tabularray}

\begin{document}
    \begin{table}
    \centering
    \caption{X}
    \label{d}
\begin{tblr}{hline{1,2,Z}=solid, vlines,
            colspec = {l  cc},
            row{1}  = {c}
            }
name            & X     & Y     \\
aaaaa-bbbbbb    & *     & **    \\
ddddd           & **    & *     \\
 \end{tblr}
    \end{table} 
\end{document}
```

However, with use of `multicolumn` instruction can be dona with `tabular` table too:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tabularray}

\begin{document}
    \begin{table}
    \centering
    \caption{X}
    \label{d}
    \begin{tabular}{|l|c|c|}
        \hline
\multicolumn{1}{|c|}{name}    & X     & Y     \\
        \hline
aaaaa-bbbbbb                & *     & **    \\
ddddd                       & **    & *     \\
        \hline
    \end{tabular}
    \end{table} 
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 4):

Although you should remember that you one argument of `\multicolumn` is the alignment, and that there are a nice  `tabulararray` package (btw, +1), in this case the simplest is just add `\hfil` to "name" cell.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\begin{document}
    \begin{tabular}{|l|c|c|}
        \hline
        \hfil name    & X    & Y \\
        \hline
        aaaaa-bbbbbb & * & ** \\
        ddddd & ** & * \\
        \hline
    \end{tabular}
\end{document}
```